# How to assign one function to different UI controls in GUIDE?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide, function-handle

I have a set of push-buttons in a figure designed in GUIDE and I want to assign one single function as their callback functions. But there is no combo-box to choose my function from in the property inspector, and when I select all buttons and click *Callback* from *View Callbacks* menu it creates multiple callback functions. Same behavior when I hit the I-DON'T-KNOW-WHAT-TO-CALL button in the property inspector.

I can handle this with some coding in `OpeningFcn` like what described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272494/one-function-for-multiple-pushbuttons-in-matlab) or just with calling `set(handle, 'method')`, but I really prefer to do it in the designing environment.

Comment: Why can't you just type it in the Callback field in the property inspector?

Comment: Your'e right @excaza, I should have tried that. I think I just expected something more convenient from such IDE.

Comment: @saastn In general, GUIDE is terrible at best. You get a lot more functionality/flexibility from writing a programmatic GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the `Callback` value within the Property Inspector. By default, it will be a custom callback for that uicontrol, but you can change it to be whatever you want.

[image]

So for me, for two push buttons they are something like the following by default:

```
@(hObject,eventdata)mygui('pushbutton2_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))    
@(hObject,eventdata)mygui('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
```

Just copy the value of one into the other and they will have the same callback.

Alternately, you can make them have a completely different callback by specifying your own value.